# tell me the correct syntax in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE socialgroupcategory (
 socialgroupcategoryid INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 creatoruserid INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
 description TEXT NOT NULL,
 displayorder INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 lastupdate INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 groups INT unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (socialgroupcategoryid),
 KEY displayorder (displayorder)
);
```

> MySQL Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'groups INT unsigned DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY
>   (socialgroupcategoryid), KEY dis' at line 8 Error Number : 1064

MySQL 5.7 - ok

MySQL 8 - error

Comment: try to enclose all *non-keywords* with back ticks (``).

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358214/2469308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUPS` has been added as a reserved keyword in MySQL 8. From [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G):

> GROUPS (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

You should use backticks to name a column/table using reserved keywords. Use the following (notice backticks around `groups`):

```
CREATE TABLE socialgroupcategory (
 socialgroupcategoryid INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 creatoruserid INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
 description TEXT NOT NULL,
 displayorder INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 lastupdate INT unsigned NOT NULL,
 `groups` INT unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (socialgroupcategoryid),
 KEY displayorder (displayorder)
);
```